Edges of vertex node
I am using a cube ...If I connect an integer  to edge of vertex node 1 edge is shoved and it is correct but why if I connect index node to edges of vertex node only 1 edge is showed instead of 8 ? 

"Edges of Vertex" and similar nodes are designed to return "one" edge.

If finds all the edges of a vertex
It sorts those edges based on the "weights" you connect (ascending)
It returns one of the edges in the sorted list corresponding to the "sort index" you select/connect

It does not return all edges of a vertex. It returns one based on a criteria.
Furthermore, the "Edges of vertex" node is expecting a context that is evaluated on "vertex domain", while your separate geometry is selected for an "edge" domain, which may lead to inconsistent results.
The context must be on a vertex domain because: "it asks for a vertex", then the "edges of vertex" node will know which is the target vertex and select its edges.

Finally, I stored the 3 edges of each vertex in a named attribute to inspect them, and only 3 vertices have edges whose index coincide with them, only one being at "sort index = 0"


Detailed inspection
For a detailed inspection, I stored all indices in the geometry for us to see the result of the "Edges of Vertice" node.


For each point, stores the indices of the 3 edges attached to it
For each point, stores its own index
For each edge, stores its own index
For each edge, stores the index of its vertice 1
For each edge, stores the index of its vertice 2

With this, we can see in the spreadsheet what is happening with your setup:


Separate geometry is working on an "edge domain" context. For each edge (which I'll call the "current edge"), it "asks" things from the nodes before it. Unless you explicitly evaluate things on different domains, "index" nodes will be retrieving the "current edge" index (there can be exceptions depending on which nodes you're using)
Index of current edge
Also index of current edge
Expects a "vertice index". Basically, you're saying: I want the vertice whose index is equal to the current edge index.
Finally, the "edges of vertex" is outputing the index of the edge connected to the vertice, whose (item 4) index is equal to the edge index

So here we see some selected edges. There are 3 of them, all of them having one vertex equal to their index:

Sort index 0:



Sort index 1:



Sort index 2:


All other sort indices are just cycling these 3 edges (because there aren't any more edges that satisfy the conditions)

Thanks Daniel , but there is a diamond socket so I understand I can use not only a single value ... I am sorry if I say stupid things but I want to understand

The diamond means something more like: for each target vertice in the context, the index may be evaluated differently.

Do you mean separate geometry node is used in bad way ?

I mean "edges of vertice" is used in a wrong context. (Edge context x Vertice context). If you have a greater goal, you can put it in your question and maybe there are other ways to achieve it. But right now it seems you're just testing the nodes.

I am just learning geometry node approach go deeply in topological nodes ... I think I have to understand very well the use of nodes to get the power of geometry node

Yes. These topology nodes were the last I learned (very recently, actually). Geometry nodes are confusing because of contexts and domains (and some nodes change contexts/domains). If you haven't grasped the idea of "context" well yet, that's where you should begin for then trying to understand the topology nodes.  This is good reading: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/fields.html

One thing I always expect from geometry nodes is the concept of 2d data (as if I could add many values to the index as you expected and get multiple outputs). But they're 1d data. The idea of multiple inputs/outputs is attached to "one per point/edge/face/instance".

@MarcoGreco, Since this topic also gets me confused and I need to consolidate my learning, I updated my answer with a deeper inspection. Take a look

Thanks Daniel for your study .. . , I found that If I connect directly the edge vertex from edges of vertex node directly to selection pink socked of separate geometry more edges are showed

That might be a data conflict.... "selection" is expecting booleans (0 or 1, false or true), when you connect anything different from 0, it will assume "true", so, basically you might be discarding only the edge of index 0.

yes I know but may be all the edges from edge index more than or equal to 1 appear only index 0 does not appear  ... is it the right output ? frankly speaking I do not know

if you use vertex index 1 or 2 from edge vertices node as imput for vertex index of edges of vertex node and make selection with compare node many edges are showed as if index node is not the right input for edges of vertex node

There is no "right input" . It depends on what you want to achieve. In every case, "edges of vertex" will return "one" edge per context element. You're creating an expression and edges will be returned if that expression is true. For using "vertex index 1 (from edge vertices)" and "sort index = 0", it will return edges if these edges are the first edge of its first vertex. If you change "sort index = 1", it will return edges if these edges are the second edge of its first vertex, and so on.

@ Daniel Moller : thank you again for your inspection that I am studying deeply ... you say that block 3 evaluate "index of current edge " my understanding (probably wrong) is that because the node 3 (in yellow) is connected to vertex index socket it should evaluate a vertex and not an edge

@MarcoGreco, no, the context is given by the "data flow"  node (the separate geometry), while the rest of the nodes "field nodes" just propagate the context backwards. The context comes from "separate geometry" and the input (red) nodes are using this context. (There are a few types of nodes that provide different contexts, but it's not the case here)

Well, in 4 it evaluates a vertex, but "a vertex whose index is the edge index (3)".

@ Daniel Moller : thank you Daniel what you are explaining now probably is the readon of my confusion !! Do you think geo node could be improved to avoid this confusion … may be also with better documentation ?

I think a better documentation regarding fields and contexts would be an interesting thing. The link I provided earlier in the comments is a half-good documentation to understand context. The "Edges of vertex" documentation has a nice example of usage. One feature that lack in geonodes is: "for each socket, which context is it working on?" - The "edges of vertex" work mostly in the context of the output (the separate geometry in your example), but the "weights" socket work on the "connected edges of this vertice" context.
